# ThreeJS load time and texture rendering problems

Tags: html, json, canvas, three.js, webgl

I have a 3D object of a chair made in Blender and exported as a .obj and .mtl. First of all, the load time is a horrendous 40+ seconds; I have no idea why (Visual Studio possibly?) Second, the images textures are not loading properly. With no ambient or directional lighting I get a silhouette. With the lighting I get a slight hint of gray to give a little depth but nothing close to the many colors in the original object. I have only been working with ThreeJS for a few days now so I'm quite new to it. Hence, I am at a loss. I have read several artciles related to my issue but none seem to solve the problem. I even went so far as to add an addon to Blender to export to .js. I could not get it to even load properly (I assume it had to do with the fact I kept the same loader info from the .OBJMTLLoader and the .JSONLoader doesn't support or needs more than what I gave; I just am not familiar enough with it know). Any ideas/suggestions? Here is my script:

`

```
    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

    <script src="js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>

    <script>

        if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var container;

        var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1e10);
            camera.position.z = 2;

            //controls
            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

            controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
            controls.zoomSpeed = 5;
            controls.panSpeed = 2;

            controls.noZoom = false;
            controls.noPan = false;

            controls.staticMoving = true;
            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.add(camera);

            //lights
            var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xCCCCCC);
            scene.add(ambient);

            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xCCCCCC);
            directionalLight.position.set(0, 0, 2).normalize();
            scene.add(directionalLight);

            //main img
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '0xCCCCCC' });

            var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener('load', function (event) {

                var geometry = event.content;
                //var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);

                scene.add(geometry, material);

            });
            loader.load('chair.obj', 'chair.mtl');


            // renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            //

            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

        }


        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            controls.handleResize();

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            render();

            controls.update();

        }

        function render() {

            var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }

    </script>
```

`

Comment: I've been playing around with a three.js editor and see that an ambient light isn't helping my cause, either. I took it out, but it's still a silhouette object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are defining a gray MeshBasicMaterial to use with your obj instead of using the material(s) that the loader will create for you, i guess.
Just use this. The "object" should have the material defined in your mtl-file.

```
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
var object = event.content;
scene.add( object );
});             
loader.load( 'chair.obj', 'chair.mtl' );
```

Concerning your load time: Could be your local server. Also, be aware that the obj file format ist quite big in raw ascii format. Also, if the mtl-file defines textures, they are maybe quite big in file size, too.

Comment: I have tried it with and without the mesh and it doesn't make a difference. The image is still black. I have also tried using the file  as JSON and I get an error with my addEventListener.

Comment: <img src="http://postimg.org/image/oy5vplebl/" >
    <img src="http://postimg.org/image/pysz917k7/" >

The first image id a chair that looks exactly like it did in blender with no textures. However, the second will not render the textures, apparently. The code stays the same except for the files.

Comment: well, does it find the texture at all and do you get any console errors? At least it seems the obj-file gets loaded.

Comment: No console errors whatsoever. How would I know if it's finding the textures or not? Could it have to do with my directional light? Here is what I'm currently using for it:

    `var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
          directionalLight.position.set(0, 0, 1).normalize();
          scene.add(directionalLight);`

Comment: maybe create a jsFiddle? That would be helpful or try changing this to  a spotlight with the appropriate parameters and a further away position?  btw: normalizing a Vec3(0,0,1) will result in (0,0,1) so you can save the normalize().

Answer (score 1):

@GuyGood was correct in my case for the long load time. I was using the python simplehttpserver and switch to a node server and no more slow texture loading problems. Check out the [threejs wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally) for other local server options.